# Strategy for showing/hiding li iwith an onClick n React without using JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, reactjs, html-lists

I am trying to hide/show an `<li>` element. I am aware that this can be done with JQuery, but I rather not mix manipulating the actual DOM with React's virtualized DOM manipulation. That being said, I have given every `<li>` element a unique name to reference, ie: an integer.

My goal is to click a button located within each `<li>` and then hide that particular `<li>` element. When I inspect the element, it is clear that each `<li>` has a unique name, but why am I not able to access the particular `<li>` when I use `element.target.name`?

```
triggerDeletePost(event) {
    var element = event.target.name
    console.log('element', element) //undefined
}




<li key = {post.post_id} name = {post.post_id}>
        <Card>
            <Card.Header>
            <userContext.Consumer>
                {()=> {
                    return(
                        <DropdownButton id="dropdown-basic-button" title="" style={{float: 'right'}}>
                            <Dropdown.Item onClick={(event)=>this.triggerDeletePost(event)}>Delete Post</Dropdown.Item>
                        </DropdownButton>
                    )
                }}
            </userContext.Consumer>
            </Card.Header>
            <Card.Body>
               <p>{post.message}</p>
            </Card.Body>
        </Card>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case `target` must be `Dropdown.Item`'s html element that actually getting clicked. It may be even deepest element of this Component root element like `<span>`, `<i>`, etc.

In order to get `name` attribute of element `<li>` - I would suggest to use [closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) method of Element class.

For example:

```
triggerDeletePost({currentTarget}) {
  const $li = currentTarget.closest('li[name]');
  const name = $li.getAttribute('name');
  console.log(name, $li) // here you have it
}
```

Comment: After following your steps, I am getting the following error: 

Cannot Read Property "closest" of undefined. I then changed currentTarget to event.target and received the same issue. Any thoughts?

Comment: You have to check browser compatibility table for method [closest (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest#Browser_compatibility) - not every browser support this method